# How do I use contact lists on New Outlook on a Mac?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, contacts

I'm using Outlook for Mac version 16.64 (22081401) on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1, with the New Outlook interface option (as opposed to Legacy).  I'd like to be able to create and use contact lists, which expand to a fixed list of other addresses, like an alias in other mail clients.

This works fine with Outlook Web App; the New Contact dropdown has a New Contact List option.  It's also available in the Legacy Outlook interface after deselecting "Hide On My Computer Folders" in Preferences.  But under New Outlook, the New Contact List function is not anywhere to be found; the options that drop down from New Contact are only "New Message" and "New Event", and I can't find any mention of it elsewhere either.

Are contact lists, or any equivalent feature, still available with New Outlook? If so, how do I create them and send email to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i know, the feature is not available in New Outlook for Mac now. More information: [The new Outlook for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439#:%7E:text=We%20always%20have%20features%20in%20active%20development%20and%20some%20of%20these%20will%20be%20available%20in%20the%20new%20Outlook%20experience%20later%20this%20year.%C2%A0).

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that per now (Sep, 2023) the Coming Soon list is still the same as it was a year ago - and thus Contact Lists aren't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can create a new Contact List in Version 16.77.1.  Under the Home tab, the New Items dropdown menu has an item Contact List.  I have not found a way to edit or delete an existing Contact List.

[image: Menu screenshot]

Comment: This is with the "Legacy Outlook" UI.  I'm asking about "New Outlook" (menu item Outlook : New Outlook) in which no such option is present as far as I can tell.  So this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ah.  That detail in your question went over my head.  My version of Outlook doesn't have a New Outlook or Legacy item under the Outlook menu.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this a while ago and found that it is not available in the new version of outlook on Mac.

As a temporary workaround, i use email templates using the following approach:

- Compose a new email
- Add all the recipients you would have saved as the contact list
- Save the email as a template.

To use it:

- Select option "File" --> "New" --> "Email from template"
- When prompted, select the Template that you saved earlier.

The above will load a new email with all the recipients you included in the template.